# Unrecognized mnemonic CHAR0?

Tags: assembly, addition, pep8-assembly

First-timer with PEP/8 code here. I'm trying to learn how to code a simple addition program. Here's what I've got so far:

```
LDA 0x0011,d
ADDA 0x0013,d
ORA 0x0015,d
STBYTEA 0x0010,d
CHAR0 0x0010,d
STOP
.BLOCK 1
.WORD 5
.WORD 3
.WORD 0x0030
.END
```

The problem I'm stumbling across is that for some reason, PEP/8 doesn't recognize CHAR0.

CHAR0 0x0010,d ;ERROR: Invalid mnemonic.

What output should I be using here?

Comment: It's "CHARO", not "CHAR0" - letter instead of digit at the end.